# BMI calculator lab can't find issue

Tags: c, function

For this lab I am not allowed to edit the main function, everything must be done in the function below main. I can't seem to find my problem here. I think it has something to do with the call to the calculateBMI function.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    FILE *fp;

    //For loop, which allows up to 4 entries.
    int main(void) {
        int i;

        fp = fopen("csis.txt", "w");
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
            calculateBMI();
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    //Function that calculates the BMI of the Input.
    double calculateBMI(int weightInPounds, int heightInInches) {
        double BMI;

        BMI = weightInPounds * 703 / heightInInches * heightInInches;

        //If BMi is less then 18.5 print this.
        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            printf("Your BMI is %d, you are underweight.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %d, you are underweight.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is between 18.5 and less then 25 print this.
        else if (BMI > 18.5 & BMI < 25) {
            printf("Your BMI is %d, you are Normal.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %d, you are Normal.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is greater then 25 and less then 30 print this.
        else if (BMI > 25 & BMI < 30) {
            printf("Your BMI is %d, you are Overweight.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %d, you are Overweight.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is greater then 30 print this.
        else (BMI > 30) {
            printf("Your BMI is %d, you are Obese.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %d, you are Obese.", BMI);
        }

        //Asks user for input weight in pounds.
        printf("What is your weight in pounds?");
        fprintf(fp, "What is your weight in pounds?");
        scanf("%d\n", weightInPounds);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", weightInPounds);

        // Asks user for input height in inches.
        printf("What is your height in inches?");
        fprintf("What is your height in inches?");
        scanf("%d\n", heightInInches);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", heightInInches);

        getchar(0);
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: Can't find your "issue" and "problem?" There are so many warnings and errors from the compiler, you should address them, one by one, as informed by the compiler. Please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: I'm sorry, was in a rush and I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many simple mistakes in your code.

1. You should define your calculateBMI function before main or You should declare it before main.
2. while calling `calculateBMI` function pass the parameter for the function / read the values inside the `calculateBMI` function.
3. if you declare BMI as double then use `%lf` as format specifier in printf statement.
4. cant give condition for else statement, so make it `else if`
5. use bracket for equation
   `BMI = weightInPounds * 703 / heightInInches * heightInInches;`
6. you should pass the address of the variable for scanf statement (i.e &variable)

here is the modified code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    FILE *fp;
double calculateBMI();
    //For loop, which allows up to 4 entries.
    int main(void) {
        int i;

        fp = fopen("csis.txt", "w");
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
            calculateBMI();
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    //Function that calculates the BMI of the Input.
    double calculateBMI(int weightInPounds, int heightInInches) {
        double BMI=0;
                //Asks user for input weight in pounds.
        printf("What is your weight in pounds?");
        fprintf(fp, "What is your weight in pounds?");
        scanf("%d\n", &weightInPounds);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", weightInPounds);

        // Asks user for input height in inches.
        printf("What is your height in inches?");
        fprintf(fp,"What is your height in inches?");
        scanf("%d\n", &heightInInches);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", heightInInches);

        BMI = (weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches);

        //If BMi is less then 18.5 print this.
        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            printf("Your BMI is %f, you are underweight.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %f, you are underweight.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is between 18.5 and less then 25 print this.
        else if (BMI > 18.5 & BMI < 25) {
            printf("Your BMI is %f, you are Normal.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %f, you are Normal.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is greater then 25 and less then 30 print this.
        else if (BMI > 25 & BMI < 30) {
            printf("Your BMI is %f, you are Overweight.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %f, you are Overweight.", BMI);
        }
        //if BMI is greater then 30 print this.
        else if(BMI > 30) {
            printf("Your BMI is %f, you are Obese.", BMI);
            fprintf(fp, "Your BMI is %f, you are Obese.", BMI);
        }



        getchar();
        return (0);
    }
```

extra info. i think the in BMI formula you should give height in meters/ convert it into meters.

Answer (score 1):

In the else if statement you used the & operator , but in this case you need to use && operator  . The & operator is a bitwise operator .
For example if you have two 4 bit variable  1001 and 1010 . You use the & operator  the result will be  1000 . 
In this case you have to use && operator
It should look like this:

```
    else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 25)
```